# Delete rows mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to delete some rows in an Excel sheet based on a cell value that is a date. Sheet 1, D6 is a date.

```
Sub SAVE()
'----- DELETE OLD ROWS -----
Dim r As Range
Dim x As Integer
Dim Monday As String
Dim Tuesday As String
Dim Wednesday As String
Dim Thursday As String
Dim Friday As String
Dim Saturday As String
Dim Sunday As String
Monday = Sheet1.Range("D6").Value
Tuesday = Sheet1.Range("D6").Value + 1
Wednesday = Sheet1.Range("D6").Value + 2
Thursday = Sheet1.Range("D6").Value + 3
Friday = Sheet1.Range("D6").Value + 4
Saturday = Sheet1.Range("D6").Value + 5
Sunday = Sheet1.Range("D6").Value + 6

For x = 5000 To 2 Step -1 '---> Change as needed

  Set r = Range("A" & Format(x))
  If UCase(r.Value) = Monday Then
    Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete
  End If

  Set r = Range("A" & Format(x))
  If UCase(r.Value) = Tuesday Then
    Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete
  End If

  Set r = Range("A" & Format(x))
  If UCase(r.Value) = Wednesday Then
    Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete
  End If

  Set r = Range("A" & Format(x))
  If UCase(r.Value) = Thursday Then
    Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete
  End If

  Set r = Range("A" & Format(x))
  If UCase(r.Value) = Friday Then
    Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete
  End If

  Set r = Range("A" & Format(x))
  If UCase(r.Value) = Saturday Then
    Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete
  End If

  Set r = Range("A" & Format(x))
  If UCase(r.Value) = Sunday Then
    Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete
  End If

Next
End Sub
```

This code works sometimes. Every so often I get a Run-time error '13' Type Mismatch. When I click debug, it highlights `If UCase(r.Value) = Monday Then`.

The error is: `r.Value = Error 2023, Monday = "7/4/2016"`

Image of the sheet it is pulling from:

[image]

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Only taking a wild stab in the dark, since we can't see the data you are running the code on, its possible the error is on the function "UCase()", passing perhaps and empty cell or something of the sort. Check through all the cells and see if you notice any strange characters or anomalies

Comment: When you click debug, what are the values of `r.Value` and `Monday` variable?

Comment: Provoke the error again. When you're in the debug window, press Ctrl+G to bring up the Immediate Window pane. In this window, type `? r.Value` and tells us the result.

Comment: Ugh, Well now it's working again! I'll look that up - It's difficult to try to get an error that only comes up every so often. I edited my posted and added the photo of the sheet it is pulling from.

Comment: It's hard for me to say from just that screencap... the ideal for us to help debug is to know both `r.Value` and `Monday` (during a runtime when the error has happened), like omegastripes said. Alternatively you can encapsulate the code to add automatic debug information.

Comment: I got the error to come up again, r.Value = Error 2023, Monday = "7/4/2016"

Comment: Error code suggests that you have `#REF!` somewhere in `A` column. You can check it using `IsError` function. It is unclear why you are using `UCase` with date values,

Comment: Thanks! What would be the best resolution for a date value?

Comment: Out of curiosity... can you again provoke the error, and tell me the output of `? r.Address`, `? i` and manually find the value of the cell you got from `r.Address` (if any)? The user above has a point about UCase, but that line of code does not affect the output of `? r.Value` so it's curious still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the code below will do what you intend:

```
Sub SAVE()
    ' Sheet1 is named "Control Panel", Sheet1 D6 has the pull date
    ' Sheet5 is named "Database", has the stored dates to delete
    '----- DELETE OLD ROWS -----
    Dim dtFrom As Date
    Dim dtUpto As Date
    Dim y As Long
    Dim vCont As Variant
    dtFrom = Sheets("Control Panel").Range("D6").Value
    dtUpto = dtFrom + 6
    With Sheets("Database")
        For y = 5000 To 2 Step -1
            vCont = .Cells(y, 1).Value
            If Not IsError(vCont) Then
                If vCont >= dtFrom And vCont <= dtUpto Then
                    .Rows(y).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It would be curious to know if your approach is faster than mine. I often wonder about the "invisible" overhead of built-in functions.

Comment: Obviously it isn't faster since it includes error check and two comparisons, so 3 refs to `Cells()` in total. BTW for my OS reference to `Cells().Value` takes about 8 mks, and `DateDiff()` call about 2 mks.

Comment: The comparison would be unfair with the error check, so naturally that is something I would not calculate with. But your report on `Cells().Value` and `DateDiff()` is interesting and probably answers the question good enough regardless.

Comment: Just coped this in.. works great! THANK YOU! Also, the date is in Sheet1 but the sheet it is deleting from is on Sheet5.. how can I make it work so when I click the macro on sheet1, it deletes on Sheet5?

Comment: @omegastripes the pull date is in Sheet1 but the sheet it is deleting from is on Sheet5.. how can I make it work so when I click the macro on sheet1, it deletes the rows on Sheet5

Comment: How do you declare `sheet1` variable (pls, don't post a code in comments, scroll up to your question and edit it)? And what are the names of your sheets where to pull from and to delete?

Comment: I added Worksheets("Sheet5").Activate in there but I get a subscript out of range.  Sheet1 is named "Control Panel", Sheet 5 is named "Database" Sheet1 D6 has the pull date.. Sheet5 has the stored dates to delete

Comment: You should refer to the sheet either by it's index `Sheets(1).Activate`, or by the name `Sheets("Control Panel").Activate`. To be specific, add the workbook object, eg: `ThisWorkBook.Sheets("Control Panel").Activate` - for the book where the macro has been launched from.

Comment: It's not necessary to `.Activate` the sheet - I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Backup your workbook and try this refactor (now modified as per omegastripes' suggestion):

```
Sub SAVE()
    '----- DELETE OLD ROWS -----
    Dim r As Range, x As Integer, y As Variant

    y = Sheet1.Range("D6").Value + 3

    For x = 5000 To 2 Step -1
        Set r = Range("A" & x)
        If DateDiff("d", y, r.Value) <= 3 Then Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't you think referencing to `Sheet1.Range("D6").Value` about 5000 times will give a little slowdown?

Comment: Perhaps :) it should be better now.

Comment: Just tried this one.. works perfectly just significantly slow.

Comment: @vsoraas I see `Range("A1")` takes 9 mks, and `Range("A" & x)` where `x` is Integer takes 10 mks..